# spring hibernate transaction junit new thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, junit4

I am using spring managed hibernate transactions

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I have a class Task that implements Runnable  that calls a method annotated with @Transactional. The method uses hibernate criteria query api to return some results.

```
class Task implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    helperDao.getResults();
  }
}

class HelperDao {
  @Transactional
  public List<?> getResults() {
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Model.class).list();
  }
}
```

I have a junit4 test class with instances autowired

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/test.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
@Transactional
public class TaskTest {
  public void testTask() {
    Thread taskThread = new Thread(new Task(), "task-thread");
    taskThread.start();
    taskThread.join();
  }
}
```

If I run the task in the main thread it returns the results but when I run it in a new thread it blocks inside the hibernate query and never returns. The log only says that hibernate has bound the query parameters. It is not loading the result set.

I am assuming this has something to do with spring transaction and hibernate session.close() but not able to figure out what needs to change to get this to execute in a different thread.

thanks much,
ash